# MutationObserver fired multiple times (but only ok if item.length == 1 item)

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I observe a div-Container with `new MutationObserver`(childlist)

If I remove (via javascript onclick) a single element from the container, the Observer is fired only once - thats ok,
but
If I remove multiple items (via javascript onclick), the Observer fired for each item that I removed...

I don't know how many item will be removed!

Has anyone an idea how I can prevent this, or to group the mutations before ?

The background is:
After each change, I make an Ajax request, to filter items - and if the Observer fired multiple times, each time an Ajax request is fired... (ex 4 times in 4ms....)

Sorry, I have no example code, but there is a live site online ->
https://www.fhstp.ac.at/de/forschung/projekte 
Look for `fetch` (please ignore the TypeError :-) )

Sorry, for the bad title, but I have no better idea...

Comment: Simply *debounce* the code.

Comment: So simple - perfect, thank you!